# How to solve Vue router change error with param?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

There are 3 buttons(HOME, CARD, LOAN) on the toolbar and when I click them, they go to `'home'`, `'list/card'`, and `'list/loan'` respectively.

This is my `router.js` code for `'list/card'` and `'list/load'`

```
{
        path: '/list/:id',
        name: 'listview',
        component: ListView
},
```

when I click the `CARD` on the loan page or `LOAN` on the card page, the URL on the URL bar of the browser is changed but the content of the page is not changed.

if I click either of these buttons on the other pages(for example `HOME` page),       it works.

This is the code when I click the button

```
gotoPage(path) { // here path='/list/loan or path='/list/card'
   this.$router.push({ path: path })
}
```

This is the code for listview component

```
created: function () {
    this.loadUsers(this.$route.params.id)
},
```

The issue is that this `created` hook function is not working in this case.

Help me, please!!

Comment: Show us how you determine which component to display within the listview.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, when loading listview page, created lifecycle hook function is not called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `updated` hook function.

Like this

```
created: function () {
    this.loadUsers(this.$route.params.id)
},
updated: function () {
    this.loadUsers(this.$route.params.id)
}
```

It will work.